# $().load() not passing variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass a variable using `$.load()` but the variable doesn't make it through. Here's the code that sets the variable from an embedded form:

```vb
'first of all determine whether there are any records
If Recordset.EOF Then
    Response.Write("No records returned.")
Else
    'if there are records then loop through the fields
%>

<form action =""> 
    <select onchange="showCustomer(this.value)">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a Transponder:</option>
        <%
            Do While NOT Recordset.Eof     
                ' list xpdrs %>
                <option value="<%=Recordset("Transponder")%>"><%=Recordset("Transponder")%></option>
            <% 
    </select>
</form>
```

I then try to call a file, pass the variable and load it onto a `<div>` with this code:

```
<div id="chartDiv" style="float:left; padding: 25px; margin-left:200px;height:700px;width:1200px;border:1px solid green "></div>
<script>
    function showCustomer(str) {
        //alert("Function showCustomer triggered!!  String is: " + str);
        $("#chartDiv").load("asp-query.asp?q=" + str);
    }
</script>
```

The variable then is part of a SQL query in the second file as:

```vb
'declare the SQL statement that will query the database
SQL = "SELECT  TOP 1 [uid], [Satellite],[Transponder],[Carrier], " &_
    "[Trace],[startfreq],[stopfreq], [traceTime], [minval],[maxval],[numpoints],[reflevel] FROM [PlotMinder].[dbo].[tblTrace] " &_
    "WHERE [Transponder] = " &  "'" & request.querystring("q") & "'"

response.write SQL & "<BR>"
```

I've tried all I could find for a week now but can't make it work.
Thanks in advance for any help you could provide.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)**

Comment: And how do you debug it (since one week)? Is `str` what you expect and correctly encoded (no sepcial char)?

Comment: Does it work as expected when you open a page directly in a browser, e.g. this way `asp-query.asp?q=bla-bla`?

Comment: And it's better use $.load('asp-query.asp', {q: str}) since there are might be special characters in the `str` variable which will be safely converted in this case.

Comment: Wolff, inside the function, alert will return the str. Is that not a good place to check?   Response.write SQL returns with 'Transponder = ", so no variable is being passed. If I enter q=bla-bla-bla it passes that. Will try what basil suggests. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, missed the first comment. How am I vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: If it doesn't work when you call the file directly then probably a value of `q` isn't read from a request. Try to check if `request.querystring("q")` contents what you passed in `q` parameter.

Comment: it works when I call the file directly.

Comment: So, it means the problem on the client side, in JS. Try `$("#chartDiv").load('asp-query.asp', {q: str})` instead of `$("#chartDiv").load("asp-query.asp?q=" + str);`, just in case.

Comment: it's in like that now:  $("#chartDiv").load('asp-query.asp', {q: str}) but still doesn't pass it. This is the SQL at the receiving file:   
SELECT TOP 1 [uid], [Satellite],[Transponder],[Carrier], [Trace],[startfreq],[stopfreq], [traceTime], [minval],[maxval],[numpoints],[reflevel] FROM [PlotMinder].[dbo].[tblTrace] WHERE [Transponder] = ''
No records returned.

Comment: What values did you pass? Are they in UTF-8? May be the encoding of the page differs from the DB one.

Comment: they come from a dropdown box. The values are like: AMC-10_02C or NSS-12_GLR09/GLL09. I've tried AMC1002C but that doesn't work either. Thanks for your continuous effort, basil.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad you've done it =)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, just as I was ready to hang myself..;-)

I added ,true) to this line:

`$( "#chartDiv" ).load( "asp-query.asp?q=" +str, true);`

and it worked. It comes from the original function

```
function showCustomer(str) {
  var xhttp;    
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "asp-query.asp?q="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();

}
```

Not sure why that change would make the function work (pass the variable). I would like an explanation, if someone has the answer. Also, @basil, is there a similar method with the line

```
$("#chartDiv").load('asp-query.asp', { q: str });
```

?
Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Quentin, I'm going to use placeholders in the SQL query to prevent injection attacks. Also, when I look at the source code of my 'client' page, I can see that I'm calling asp-query.asp, like so:
<div id="chartDiv" style="float:left; margin-left:200px;height:700px;width:1200px;border:1px solid green "></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showCustomer(str) {
//alert("Function showCustomer triggered!!  String is: " +str);
$( "#chartDiv" ).load( "asp-query.asp?q=" +str, true);
}
How can I hide that? Thanks!

Comment: The similar method is http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, and in a success callback you should set retrieved html (response) in your container manually: `$('#chartDiv').html(response)`